# Sql oracle trigger error

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Hi I was wondering if someone can help me adjust my trigger. I have only been working with triggers for only couple of weeks and quite new to it. My trigger is suppose to add $75 per day a boat is return late to the customer_balance account. If the boat is return early then it adds $20 per day the boat was return early to the customer_Balance account. I keep getting errors trying to get this trigger to work right so I was wondering can help or explain to me what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

```
create or replace trigger trig_penalty
        before update of customer_balance
    on customer  for each row
declare
   i number;
   s varchar(20);
begin
   select customer_balance into s
     from customer
    where customer_ID =:new.customer_id;

    i := :new.charter_returndate - :old.charter_duedate;
    if i>=0 then
       dbms_output.put_line('Late return fee added');
       update customer
          set customer_balance=customer_balance+75*i
        where customer_id=s;
    else 
       dbms_output.put_line('Early return refund added');
       update customer
          set customer_balance=customer_balance+20*i
        where customer_id=s;
    end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: What are the errors? Put it on your question.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to understand that a trigger is an artifact that work for (in your case) each row that are being modified. So you are doing unecessary work on it.

Try this:

```
create or replace trigger trig_penalty
        before update of customer_balance
    on customer  for each row
declare
   i number;
   s varchar(20);
begin
   --You dont need to select the id is it is already on :new.customer_id
   -- your trigger is for UPDATE
   ---select customer_balance into s
   ---  from customer
   --- where customer_ID := :new.customer_id;

    i := :new.charter_returndate - :old.charter_duedate;
    if i>=0 then
       --Do not use dbms_output in an internal object.
       --dbms_output.put_line('Late return fee added');

       --You don't need to run an update for an update trigger you
       -- just need to set the new value on :NEW.FIELD
       --update customer
       --   set customer_balance=customer_balance+75*i
       -- where customer_id=s;

       --As you select this value I'm using the OLD which means the value that 
       --Was already on the table

       :NEW.customer_balance := :OLD.customer_balance+75*i;

    else 
       --dbms_output.put_line('Early return refund added');
       --update customer
       --   set customer_balance=customer_balance+20*i
       -- where customer_id=s;

       :NEW.customer_balance := :OLD.customer_balance+20*i; 

    end if;
end;
/
```

That should do it. Remeber for an BEFORE trigger the value setted on :NEW will end up on the table.

Comment: thank you for your input, but I still receive errors when I adjust my code to what you had suggested. 
PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.CHARTER_RETURNDATE'
PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.CHARTER_DUEDATE'
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of following: := . ( @ % ; indicator
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ELS"

Comment: Did you put the `:` before the new and old words??

Comment: and does CHARTER_DUEDATE is a field from customer_balance ?

Comment: I made a little mistake. on the attrib sign it is `:=` not `=` ive corrected it.

Comment: thanks that avoid one of the problem. my last question is what does it mean when it indicates 'bad bind variable'? Judging from the error it saying something is wrong with the 'new.charter_returndate' and 'old.charter_duedate' but I cant figure out whats wrong with it.

Comment: This is just telling you that it can't find that variable on your table. E.g. you have a table `A (id, name, email)` and on a `before update trigger on A` you are trying to use `:NEW.address` adress is a field that doesnt exists on `A` table.

Comment: 'charter_duedate' and 'charter_returndate' are from a table called charter while 'customer_balance' is from the customer table.

Comment: the difference between the 'charter_duedate' and 'charter_returndate' will return me the number of days late or early and 'X' the amount depending on which one it is therefore, that total number will be put on the 'customer_balance' which is on a different table. so how would i reference that in the code? because customer_balance and charter_duedate and charter_returndate are from different tables.

Comment: In that case you can have select statements to select theese data. Just put a select into clause to variables that you define like you did with S, you just don't need to do a select on the table that the trigger belongs unless you wanna some grouped data, but this is another thing. Put the structure of your table and some data example and how it should be after the trigger execute then I will update my answer.